# Anatomy of a Rails Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm wondering if anyone has a good resource detailing exactly what happens when a browser makes a request to a rails app. I'm interested in everything: how the server handles the connection, how the route gets parsed, when does middleware come in, and so on. I would love to see something detailed all the way down to exactly what methods get called, and what objects get instantiated.

I feel like I don't have a great handle on all the details, and this causes me to grope in the dark for the best solution to certain problems. Any suggestions for how to learn more about this are welcome.

Comment: Have a search around for `"[ruby on] rails internals."`

Comment: [close] This question is overly broad.  Try programmers exchange perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out RailsCasts.com

these episodes give some pointers on how to dig deeper into the Rails source code:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/231-routing-walkthrough

http://railscasts.com/episodes/232-routing-walkthrough-part-2

http://railscasts.com/episodes/299-rails-initialization-walkthrough

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of any free online resources, but [Crafting Rails Applications](http://pragprog.com/book/jvrails/crafting-rails-applications) covers much of what you're asking for.